# Plus integer with string in C

Tags: c

I have a sample code in C below:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    int out = 4 + '4';
    printf("%d",out);
    return 0;
}
```

When I run it, the output value it return is 56. Can someone explain why?

Comment: Visit  [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/)  `4: 52` in ASCII code representation. when we add 4 to 52 we have 56. all `char` values in `C` cast to correspond integer

Comment: I suggest  add a new line after last output to screen. `printf("%d \n",out);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASCII value of '4' is 52.

Char value '4' has integer value 52 which is its ASCII Code.
This is added to integer value 4.

Thus the result 56

Answer (score 3):

`'4'` is a representation of the `int` value 52. 4 + 52 = 56.

Comment: `'4'` is an `int`

Comment: @M.M You are correct, fixed. Was thinking in C++.